# How do I write a method that can take either a DataGridView or a ListView as input?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, datagridview

I am using the following two methods to persist column information about a DataGridView and a ListView.

I notice the methods are very similar and in fact I use the same data structure to store the column settings in. The properties I am storing for each column are things like, Visible, Width, DisplayIndex

How can I re-write this so I have a single function that can handle a DataGridView or a ListView?

I have thought about investigating whether both DataGridView and ListView inherit from a common class or implement a common interface - but I am not sure how to find this out.

Also I have thought about extending each class to implement a common interface... but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
 public void SaveDataGridView ( DataGridView view)
 {
      foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in view.Columns)
      {
           // save properties     
      }
 }

 public void SaveDataListView(ListView view)
 {
      foreach (ColumnHeader col in view.Columns)
      {
           // save properties   
      }
 }
```

Comment: I would say you are out-of-luck. I looked at the class inheritance tree, there's no hope there for you.  If you are saving the column state in a common type, within the loops, that's pretty good right there. I would call it a day and find some other part of the App to 'improve'.

:)

Comment: What is inside `// save properties`?

Comment: And why do you loop Columns collection? Why no [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) and [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx) accordingly? They both implement `ILIst` only too.

Comment: It was set up information about the columns that I wanted to save. Such as column width and position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way until use `dynamic` keyword what will not increase the performance.

[DataGridView.Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.aspx) and [ListView.Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnheadercollection.aspx) have no common base type (except `IList`, try but I doubt about any luck). Neither [ColumnHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.aspx) and [DataGridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx) have too.

Answer (score 0):

They both inherit from the [Control class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). So you could write a function like this:

```
public void SaveView(Control view)
{
    if(view is DataGridView)
    {
        //stuff
    }
    if(view is ListView)
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Control is pretty generic, so this function doesn't make a lot of sense because there is a ton of valid parameters. Unfortunately, the Grid and List do not inherit from a more specific parent class.

Comment: It's almost the same as OP's code. He can name both methods equally so make them an overload of the single method so your codes will be fully equal.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing the following

```
interface IView
{
   void SaveView(Control control );
}

public class GridViewHelper : IView
{
    public void SaveView(Control control)
    {
        var view = (DataGridView)control;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in view.Columns)
        {
            // save properties
        }
    }
}

public class ListViewHelper : IView
{

    public void SaveView(Control control)
    {
        var view = (ListView)control;
        foreach (ColumnHeader  col in view.Columns)
        {
            // save properties
        }
    }
}
```